# Laravel- Can I random data from database with probability?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, probability

I have following tables like below:

```
             product
         ----------------
         - id

         - rarity

         - name
```

```php
rarity

s: lest chance
a
b
```

So, my question is that how can I random those data with probability with rarity? I know that **inRandomOrder()** will random data from database. But, How can I set where product that is rarity=s is lest chance to output?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done directly in sql. What you can do is pick 10 random items of rarity 'a', 8 (f.ex.) of rarity 'b' and 1 of rarity 's' and merge them in a collection. Then  take a random pick from that collection.

Comment: Thank @DimitriMostrey for your help. Is it take too much time?